# Finding cosets from symmetric subgroup $S_3$ of symmetric group $S_4$ where $S_3 = \{\phi\in S_4\mid\phi(4) = 4\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

This question confused me a bit.

> Symmetric group $S_3$ is a subgroup of symmetric group $S_4$ where $S_3 = \{\phi \in S_4 \mid \phi(4) = 4\}$

We were told to find all the different cosets from $S_3$ using this theorem that said

> $aH = bH$ if and only if $a^{-1} b \in H$

Our lecturer said that we need to find an element $\phi \in S_4$ but $\phi \notin S_3$ and later we got that the cosets are $S_3, \phi S_3, \phi^2 S_3$ and $\phi^3 S_3$.

I don't really understand, why it should be $\phi \in S_4$ but $\phi \notin S_3$? What would happen if $\phi \in S_3$?

Comment: I think it's a typo.   Should be  $a^{-1}b\in H $.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry there was a typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\phi S_3$ means all products $\phi \sigma$ where $\sigma$ ranges over $S_3.$ So if $\phi$ is actually *in* $S_3$ this would just end up being only $S_3$ since multiplying all elements of a group by one of its elements just gives that group back. [a subgroup is in particular a group]

Comment: Ah, I see. So basically we wouldn't get $S_4$ if we choose $\phi$ which is in $S_3$. So that's why we shouldn't choose $\phi \in S_3$. Am I getting that right?

Comment: @alpha00 Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi\in S_3$, then $\phi S_3=S_3$.

There are four cosets.  If we choose $\phi=(1234) $, say, then they are $S_3,\phi S_3,\phi^2S_3,\phi^3S_3$.

Not every $\phi\in S_4\setminus S_3$ works.  For instance,  $(24) $  has order *two*, so only gives two cosets.

Comment: This is because $S_3$ is not normal in $S_4$, @alpha00.